# Does Gadfly support LaTeX in plot titles and labels?

Tags: latex, julia, gadfly

I am interested in using Greek letters and math symbols in the title and labels for a Gadfly plot in Julia.

Does anyone know of a way to do this, or is this not supported (yet)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX strings (i.e. `L"string"`) are not supported, but you can still use greek letters for labels.  For example:

```
using Gadfly
z=linspace(0,2*pi,20)
plot(x=z, y=sin(z), Guide.YLabel("αβγ"))
```

These greek characters can be made in the Julia REPL or iJulia notebook by typing in the LaTeX command and pressing tab (so typing `\alpha` and pressing [TAB] makes `α`, etc.)

You can also get other math symbols this way.  For example `\sum` [TAB] `x\dot` [TAB] `\_j` [TAB] `\^2` [TAB] will get you `∑ẋⱼ²`

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, @Ben. That seems pretty obvious in retrospect, I don't know why I didn't try that first.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, it looks like [LaTeX support for plot labels and such in Gadfly does not exist](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/julia-users/4QY2hzaR_EI).

However, HTML tags such as <sup> and <sub> let you do a bit of text formatting, and you can also use [HTML 4.0 character entity, decimal character and hexadecimal character references](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).